# find string startwith (regular expression)

Tags: c#, regex

i'm trying to find the first string in a list that starts between E to M (E-M);

```
startIndexOfMiddleRange = list.IndexOf(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.StartsWith(())))
```

what is the pattern or the way i should do that?

thanks for the helpers

Comment: Hi Gilad

i have 2 variables

            startIndexOfMiddleRange = list.IndexOf(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Length > 0 && x.Name[0] >= 'ח' && x.Name[0] <= 'נ'));
            endIndexOfMiddleRange = list.IndexOf(list.LastOrDefault(x => x.Name.Length > 0 && x.Name[0] <= 'נ' && x.Name[0] >= 'ח'));

i have a sorted list and i want to search in the list the first string that start with a letter between "ח-מ"
and the same for the last string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex solution:

`^[E-M]` - This pattern should work.

- `^` means "starts with"
- `[E-M]` limits the range to E-M, and since you're not using any modifiers on it, it will only select a single character.

That being said, using regular expressions for this seems like overkill when you could simply do:

```
startIndexOfMiddleRange = list.IndexOf(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Length > 0 && x.Name[0] >= 'E' && x.Name[0] <= 'M'));
```

Assuming `list` is a `List<T>`, you could simplify it more:

```
startIndexOfMiddleRange 
    = list.FindIndex(x => x.Name.Length > 0 && x.Name[0] >= 'E' && x.Name[0] <= 'M');
```

Comment: Hii Jhon
thank you for your rapid response.
it works for me now.

but still, i want to try it with a regulat expression pattern.
i didn't find the correct method in the Regex class to do so.

do you know how?

Comment: @ofer [`Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, "^[E-M]")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7.2) ought to be the method you need.